# Bayesian Network Python

Tags: python, bayesian-networks, pgmpy

How can I find the Bayesian network (of a survey data that I have) using python. I am planning to use the pgmpy library and test different structure learning algorithms (like: PC, Hill climbing, Tabu, K2.....) to find the network and dependencies of the variables. Can someone help me on how to start with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try pyAgrum (https://agrum.gitlab.io, https://pyagrum.readthedocs.io). Many notebooks can be found from [http://webia.lip6.fr/~phw/aGrUM/docs/last/notebooks/](http://webia.lip6.fr/%7Ephw/aGrUM/docs/last/notebooks/).

Answer (score 0):

The [bnlearn library](https://erdogant.github.io/bnlearn) can be useful in this case. There are many examples and a Colab [notebook notebook](https://erdogant.github.io/bnlearn/pages/html/Blog.html#colab-notebook). *Disclaimer: I am the author of this library.*